# GestureDetector doesn't work when i use ListView.builder with Transform

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to position the containers in the center of the screen using Transform and I want GestureDetector to work on each Container, but, in this case, when I click on one of these containers it doesn't work, it's like there's something on top of it and that doesn't allow onTap to work.

When my Matrix4 looks like this GestureDetector works:

```
Matrix4(
  1, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 1, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 1,
)..rotateZ(_rotate[index].value),
```

But when I add 100 to Matrix4 it doesn't work:

```
Matrix4(
 1, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 1, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 1, 0, 
 0, 100, 0, 1,
)..rotateZ(_rotate[index].value),
```

Full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class TransformPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TransformState createState() => _TransformState();
}

class _TransformState extends State<TransformPage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  //Variables
  AnimationController _animationController;
  List<Color> _color = [Colors.red, Colors.blue, Colors.indigo, Colors.green];
  List<Animation> _rotate = List<Animation>(4),
      _sizeWidth = List<Animation>(4),
      _sizeHeight = List<Animation>(4);
  Animation _curve;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2));
    _curve = CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.ease);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      _sizeWidth[i] = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 120).animate(_curve);
      _sizeHeight[i] = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 120).animate(_curve);
      _rotate[i] = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 2.35).animate(_curve);
    }
    _animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text("Testing"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 4,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print(index);
            },
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Transform(
                  transform:
                      Matrix4(
                        1, 0, 0, 0, 
                        0, 1, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 1, 0, 
                        0, 100, 0, 1,
                      )..rotateZ(_rotate[index].value),
                  child: Container(
                    width: _sizeWidth[index].value,
                    height: _sizeHeight[index].value,
                    color: _color[index],
                  ),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I already tried using Positioned, but the result is the same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `Transform` widget, has a special way to deal with his `child`, It changes its content the way you want it to be, but its reference remains on the main widget, I had the same thing when I used `Transform.scale`.

If you want the `ListView` widget to move away from the top edge, use the `Padding` widget,
it is worked, I copied your code to my project and **Show debug paint**, The result was like this :

with this code :

```
Matrix4(
 1, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 1, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 1, 0, 
 0, 100, 0, 1,
)..rotateZ(_rotate[index].value),
```

the result is :

[image]

As for this code:

```
 Matrix4(
     1, 0, 0, 0, 
     0, 1, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 1, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 1,
    )..rotateZ(_rotate[index].value),
```

the result is :
[image]

the result with `Padding` widget is:

[image]

*Note:* `onTap` It actually  works in the middle square